# Refactoring Code into a MVC Pattern under the Constraint of a Library God Object

Tags: python, object-oriented-design, refactoring

I have 1000 LOC that I plan to refactor into different files and functions. The goal is to be able to test the business logic independently from the visual display. Hence, I am considering an MVC pattern.

One of the challenges is that I repeatedly need access to (properties and methods of) a unique instance of an object, let us call it a session object, which stems from a closed source library. That is why I ended up with a long code in the first place, which is largely procedural/functional.

I will pursue this object in Python 2.7.

1. How can I transition from "spaghetti code" to a decent "lasagna"
   with layers, without ending up with "ravioli code" that is too
   modular?
2. How can I concretely work with layers (including MVC) in Python and the
   object+folder structure?
3. How can I achieve modularity when I need to
   make multiple calls to an instance of a session object (due to its
   God-like nature)?

Comment: consider using [Anti-Corruption layer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/184464/31260) to prevent that library from influencing the rest of the code

Comment: @gnat That basically answers my question!